# How to change links in list.js pagination to from href="#" to href="?page="?

Tags: pagination, href, list.js

I want to change links in list.js pagination:
https://listjs.com/docs/pagination/

Before:
`<ul class="pagination"> <li class="disabled"><a class="page" href="#">...</a></li> <li><a class="page" href="#" data-i="2" data-page="5">2</a></li> <li><a class="page" href="#" data-i="3" data-page="5">3</a></li> <li><a class="page" href="#" data-i="4" data-page="5">4</a></li> <li><a class="page" href="#" data-i="5" data-page="5">5</a></li> <li><a class="page" href="#" data-i="6" data-page="5">6</a></li> <li class="disabled"><a class="page" href="#">...</a></li> </ul>`

From:
`<li><a href="#">3</a></li>`

To:
`<li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>`

I tried
`$(".pagination-bar .pagination li a.page").attr("href", "?page=");`